# xamarin forms. Ipad no render full screem

Tags: xamarin

I'm using xamarin forms, When I run on an ipad, this does not render ful screen. What should I configure?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqZfR.png)

Comment: That is an iPhone app running on an iPad.  You need to open the project properties and set it to Universal (iPhone + iPad)

Answer (score 3):

In the iOS project locale the **Info.plist** file and double click on it.

There change the Device Family from **iPhone/iPod** to **Universal**

[image: info.plist file]